# using pthread_cond_broadcast with no mutex or waiting thread?

Tags: linux, pthreads

Assuming some `pthread_cond_t condvar;` properly initialized with [pthread_cond_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_init.html) am I allowed to [pthread_cond_broadcast](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) it *without* any mutex locked and thread blocked with [pthread_cond_timedwait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) on it?

I tend to understand that it is possible (with a well defined "no-op" behavior), but I am not entirely sure. This is how I am understanding

> The pthread_cond_signal() and pthread_cond_broadcast() functions have no effect if there are no threads currently blocked on cond.

My scenario is a weird case where no thread is calling `pthread_cond_timedwait` on that condvar, but I don't want to special-case and avoid the broadcast. So the only thread using that condvar is the one calling `pthread_cond_broadcast` (in other words, the cond var is essentially useless in such case, but I try to avoid duplicating code...).

PS. My OS is Linux/Debian with GNU libc, but I prefer a general confirmation about POSIX standard. And [Calling `pthread_cond_signal` without locking mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544234/calling-pthread-cond-signal-without-locking-mutex) is not the same question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544234/calling-pthread-cond-signal-without-locking-mutex

Comment: That is not the same question. There is only one thread involved on that condvar.

Comment: Then your scenario makes no sense to me, and the answers there already say it's "ok" to broadcast outside a mutex.